# how to reduce the amount of functions that defines pointer function

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, function-pointers, virtual-functions

i'm implementing some pointer functions/Callbacks in my code as follow:

```
typedef WndDyn* (Edit_t)(Point2d* pThis, const EditParams& EditParams);
Edit_t g_Edit_CB{ nullptr };
typedef WndDyn* (*Show_t)(const Point2d* pThis, const EditParams& EditParams);
Show_t g_Show_CB{ nullptr };
// Punkt3d
typedef WndDyn* (*Edit3d_t)(Point3d* pThis, const EditParams& EditParams);
Edit3d_t g_Edit3d_CB{ nullptr };
typedef WndDyn* (*Show3d_t)(const Point3d* pThis, const EditParams& EditParams);
Show3d_t g_Show3d_CB{ nullptr };
.
.
// Vector2d
.
.
```

After a few moments I realized that I am repeating the pointer function and I am only changing my element which is Point_2d/Point_3d/....
Could someone help me to reduce the functions. I'm thinking about implementing virtual pure functions, but I usually implement them with functions and not pointer functions, so I have no idea how to do it. I would be very grateful if someone could help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: this feels like you need to do a C++ tutorial on classes, then? Because what you're building actually seems to intend to be classes with methods.

Comment: The last `typedef` also differs from the previous ones by the return type. Is that a typo?

Comment: Guys, thank you for the interest, but I just tried to write the part where I have diffuclty, but this is not my inteare code

Comment: @paolo it was only a tipping error  but they are all the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++11 (which I assume you have available as you're using `nullptr`), you can use an [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template <typename T>
using EditParamsCallback_t = WndDyn* (*)(T, const EditParams&);

int main() {
    using Edit_t = EditParamsCallback_t<Point2d*>;
    Edit_t g_Edit_CB{nullptr};

    using Show_t = EditParamsCallback_t<const Point2d*>;
    Show_t g_Show_CB{nullptr};

    // Punkt3d
    using Edit3d_t = EditParamsCallback_t<Point3d*>;
    Edit3d_t g_Edit3d_CB{nullptr};

    using Show3d_t = EditParamsCallback_t<const Point3d*>;
    Show3d_t g_Show3d_CB{nullptr};

    // Vector2d

}
```

Comment: i'm really thankfull for your help the alias template are a good solution in my case